startRecording(saveDirectory) is not working as expected
It returns true that it is starting the recording, but when ending the recording it does not save the file in specified saveDirectory
Also checked with File(recordPath).exists() it returns false, no file is saved after ending the recording
Tried flutter_vlc_player to record video/stream footage from drone to flutter app but there is no saved file after recording

Android, IOS, Windows ? Code?

I'm using Android platform and here's my code:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:inspek_app/instances/logger.dart';
import 'package:inspek_app/screens/camera/widgets/BottomControls.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const CameraScreen({super.key});
@override
State createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}
//to be continued

class _CameraScreenState extends State {
double zoomStatus = 1;
bool recording = false;
String saveDirectory = "";
final droneSourceUrl = "rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264";
final stockSourceUrl =
"https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2023/10/12/184734-873923034_large.mp4";
late final VlcPlayerController _vlcViewController;
void onZoom() {
if (zoomStatus != 3) {
setState(() {
zoomStatus++;
});
} else {
setState(() {
zoomStatus = 1;
});
}
}

Future startRecording() async {
bool recordingStarted = false;
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
setState(() {
recording = true;
final timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
saveDirectory = '${directory.path}/recordings/$timestamp.mp4';
logger.i('saveDirectory: $saveDirectory');
});
final result = await _vlcViewController.startRecording(
  saveDirectory,
);
recordingStarted = result ?? false;


if (recordingStarted) {
logger.i('Recording started: $recordingStarted');
} else {
logger.w('Recording have not started');
}
}
Future stopRecording() async {
setState(() {
recording = false;
});
final recordingStopped = await _vlcViewController.stopRecording();
if (recordingStopped != null && recordingStopped) {
logger.i('Recording stopped: $recordingStopped');
final saveDirectoryFileExists = await File(saveDirectory).exists();
logger.i("saveDirectoryFileExists: $saveDirectoryFileExists");

final futures = await Future.wait([
File(saveDirectory).exists(),
File("/storage/emulated/0/$saveDirectory").exists(),
File("/sdcard/$saveDirectory").exists(),
]);
for (var element in futures) {
logger.i("element: $element");
}
} else {
logger.w('Recording have not stopped');
}
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_vlcViewController = VlcPlayerController.network(
droneSourceUrl,
autoPlay: true,
autoInitialize: true,
hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
);
_vlcViewController.addOnInitListener(() {
  logger.i('_vlcViewController init');
});
_vlcViewController.addOnRendererEventListener((p0, p1, p2) {
  logger.i('p0=$p0, p1=$p1, p2=$p2');
});

}
